# Displaying a view from inside a view using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

I have an `index.html` file that has a view that is defined by `<div ui-view="main"></div>`

The `HomePageModuleConfig.js` where this view is defined looks like this:

```
var homePageState = {
    url: '/HomePage/', //the url that will trigger the template and controller to be called
    views: {
        "main": {
            controller: 'HomePageController',
            templateUrl: 'HomePage/HomePage.tpl.html' //template paths are relative to the app folder
        }
    }
};

$stateProvider.state("HomePage", homePageState);
```

Inside `HomePage/HomePage.tpl.html` I have another view defined like this: `<div ui-view="tableGrid"></div>`

I thought that I could render the `tableGrid` view by adding another another state to the stateProvider like this:

```
var archiveState = {
    parent: 'HomePage',
    url: "/Archive/",
    views: {
      "tableGrid@HomePage" : {
        controller: 'ArchiveController',
        templateUrl: 'Archive/Archive.tpl.html' //template paths are relative to the app folder
      }
    }
};
```

Then tacking it on:

`$stateProvider.state("HomePage", homePageState).state('Archive', archiveState);`

But when I visit /Archive/ nothing loads.

Edit: When I inspect the page after visiting /Archive/, the `<div ui-view"main"></div>` has nothing in it.

When I visit /HomePage/ the `main` template renders as expected.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunker link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that you do not see anything on url

```
#/Archive/
```

you should know, that url is inherited from parent

```
#/HomePage//Archive/
```

> Other words, the parent(s) url is added as a prefix to current state url defintion

And yes, there are so many `//` signs above, because url should rather be defined like this:

```
var homePageState = {
    // url: "/HomePage/", do not add slash at the end
    url: '/HomePage',
    ...
var archiveState = {
    parent: 'HomePage',
    // url: "/Archive/", do not add slash at the end
    url: "/Archive",
...
```

Another option how to solve the issue with parent url being prefixed is *(doc link and cite)*:

#### [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-)

> If you want to have absolute url matching, then you need to prefix your url string with a special symbol '^'.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {
     url: '/contacts',
     ...
  })
  .state('contacts.list', {
     url: '^/list',
     ...
  });
```

> So the routes would become:
>
> - **`'contacts'`** state matches "/contacts"
> - **`'contacts.list'`** state matches "/list". The urls were not combined because ^ was used.

Comment: If that helped, great! Enjoy mighty UI-Router, sir;)